# Access non-static property from member class

Tags: c++, class

I have the following two classes:

```
class B
{
    public:
        B();
        ~B();
        void Method()
        {
            //Possible to access "int Member" of class A here without passing a pointer?
        }
};

class A
{
    private:
        class B;
    public:
        A();
        ~A();
        int Member;
};
```

Class B instances are only constructed in class A. Is it now possible to access non-static members of class A in the method of class B without explicitly passing a pointer of A to the method? I would consider my code "nicer" to just call "InstanceOfB.Method()" instead of "InstanceOfB.Method(this)".

Comment: Like you do in Java with nested classes? You can't.

Comment: Why would you like to do that in the first place? #curious

Comment: To be honest: Just because it looks cleaner to me and it saves you a minimum of work. And as we see in vz0's answer, interest seems to have been there so that Java supports nested classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you do in [Java with nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)? You can't. In C++ you need to explicitly pass the instance around, the only exception being `this`.

Comment: I did not know about the concept of nested classes in Java, but according to the example at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html this seems exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your answer which I will accept as soon as possible.

Comment: Java just passes a pointer under the covers. It does not achieve anything you cannot achieve here.

Comment: In Java its syntactic sugar for passing the pointer under the hood.